# Connect to Raspberry Pi from Windows phone through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, windows, connection

Is it possible to connect a windows phone application created in C# (or any other language) to raspberry pi through Bluetooth?

I know that C# has Bluetooth library, thus you can  make Bluetooth connection using C#, But I have never actually seen a Windows phone application connecting to Raspberry pi  through Bluetooth.

Comment: You can try doing a server client in C# and run it on Mono on the Pi. Problem is that you have to compile Mono for best results..and it takes hours. :(  But works well! Windows Universal Apps coming to Pi soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about programming Windows Phones : but here's a bit of a "poor man's" Bluetooth experiment to try:

I'm assuming the Pi's Bluetooth adapter is up and running here and has previously been paired with your phone.

Install 'obexpushd':

```
$ sudo apt-get install obexpushd
```

Now check your adapter has a Bluetooth Address - and make a note of the device name (probably hci0):

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

$ mkdir bluetooth
$ cd bluetooth
$ obexpushd -d -n -B hci0
```

Now send a 'note' or 'contact' (or other files, including images in fact) from your phone to the Pi - obexpushd should respond with some messages like:

```
[...]
0.1: got 3 bytes of streamed data
0.1: Sending response code 0
0.1: OBEX_EV_STREAMAVAIL, OBEX_CMD_CONNECT
0.1: got 0 bytes of streamed data
0.1: Sending response code 0
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQ, OBEX_CMD_PUT
0.1: Sending response code 0
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQDONE, OBEX_CMD_PUT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQHINT, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
0.1: Sending response code 0
0.1: Sending response code 0
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQ, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
0.1: OBEX_EV_REQDONE, OBEX_CMD_DISCONNECT
```

You can then kill (ctrl-c) obexpushd.
There should be a text (or whatever type you sent) file in the directory with the content.

You can call obexpushd with the '-s' flag - which hands control over to a script to do whatever you want with it.

To go the other way - you can use 'obexftp' like this:

```
/usr/bin/obexftp --nopath --noconn --uuid none --bluetooth $DEVICE --channel 9 -p $FILE
```

(Where $DEVICE is the BT address of your phone [which you 'hcitool scan' for], and $FILE is just a filename).

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/obexpushd.1.html

Comment: okay thanks, i ordered raspberry pi 2 and should be here in 2 weeks, i'll let you know if it works then

Comment: Hope you have success - you will need to purchase a Bluetooth adapter for the pi of course - the cheap (~£3) ones will do but are a pain to pair I have found (legacy pairing only) , the more expensive newer ones (I have a Belkin) are easier to pair, but this is a whole other topic !